# Print html instead of plain text

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, wait

Hello Im trying to print html code , and iframe to be more precise.
when I add my html Iframe code it prints but plain text .
I would like to see the actual Iframe with content.
Thank you

```
<script>
const messages = ['<iframe src="https://stvkr.com/v2/click-Aw0XO-8X5JXO-rJ2rv-d6edfeee2?tl=1"></iframe>', '<iframe src="https://stvkr.com/v2/click-Aw0XO-8X5JXO-rJ2rv-wwwwwedfd12?tl=1"></iframe>' , '<iframe src="https://stvkr.com/v2/cliedAw0XO-8X5JXO-rJ2rv-d6edfd12?tl=1"></iframe>'];
let cnt = 0;
const show = () => {
    if (cnt >= messages.length) return;
    document.body.append(document.createTextNode(messages[cnt]));
    cnt++;
};
setInterval(show,2000)

</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any iframe in your code

Comment: Put the code you want to print into a `<pre></pre>` element and print the contents of that. Or, set the HTML you want to print into an element using `.textContent`.

Comment: You're missing a quote just before the first `iframe`.

Comment: yes sorry but it still prints plain text

Comment: I am not very familiar with Javascript, I found this code online , and its exaclty what I want to accomplish but with Iframes

Answer (score -1):

You can try one of these:

This one uses `innerHTML` on body so it can break things:

```js
const messages = ['<iframe src="https://stvkr.com/v2/click-Aw0XO-8X5JXO-rJ2rv-d6edfeee2?tl=1"></iframe>', '<iframe src="https://stvkr.com/v2/click-Aw0XO-8X5JXO-rJ2rv-wwwwwedfd12?tl=1"></iframe>', '<iframe src="https://stvkr.com/v2/cliedAw0XO-8X5JXO-rJ2rv-d6edfd12?tl=1"></iframe>'];
let cnt = 0;
const show = () => {
  if (cnt >= messages.length) return;
  document.body.innerHTML += messages[cnt];
  cnt++;
};
setInterval(show, 100)
```

This one wraps iframes in divs so it's not perfect either:

```js
const messages = ['<iframe src="https://stvkr.com/v2/click-Aw0XO-8X5JXO-rJ2rv-d6edfeee2?tl=1"></iframe>', '<iframe src="https://stvkr.com/v2/click-Aw0XO-8X5JXO-rJ2rv-wwwwwedfd12?tl=1"></iframe>', '<iframe src="https://stvkr.com/v2/cliedAw0XO-8X5JXO-rJ2rv-d6edfd12?tl=1"></iframe>'];
let cnt = 0;
const show = () => {
  if (cnt >= messages.length) return;
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.innerHTML = messages[cnt];
  document.body.append(div);
  cnt++;
};
setInterval(show, 100)
```

Comment: `.innerHTML` should be avoided whenever possible. If you were to have `document.body.innerHTML...` it would obliterate every event handler within the `body` that was added with `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you are right. I would like to use `document.createElement('empty element')` but it's not an option I guess. Any idea how to append without a wrapper?

Comment: Appending with `.append()` is the preferred way. I don't know what you mean by `'empty element'`.

Comment: `document.body.append('<iframe src=""</iframe>')` results in appending text, not html

Comment: `document.body.append("<pre><iframe.....></iframe></pre>");` Or. create a new element and set the `.textContent` of that element to some HTML and then append that element to the `document`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus it still is a text, not html

Comment: `const div = document.createElement("div");
div.textContent = "<iframe src='https://example.com'></iframe>";
document.body.append(div);
`

Comment: If you want the HTML to be parsed, then: `const frame = document.createElement("iframe");
frame.src = "https://example.com";
document.body.append(frame);`